# Open id not redirecting to the correct login page

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, openid, angular-oauth2-oidc

i followed the example 
https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/aktuelles/authentication-in-angular-2-with-oauth2-oidc/
  here and also used the same login details .

I dont have any access to backed staff except the config they provided and url staff .

when l try to do the same as below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService, JwksValidationHandler, AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

   config  : AuthConfig;
  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    this.config = new AuthConfig();

   /*
 this.config.loginUrl  = "https://my-identity-domain.azurewebsites.net/connect/authorize"; 
    this.config.clientId = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    this.config.redirectUri = window.location.origin + '/home';
    this.config.scope = "openid profile email ccxxxxx";
    this.config.responseType = 'code';

   */
  this.config.issuer =  'https://my-identity-domain.azurewebsites.net/identity';

  // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login window.location.origin + '/login'
  this.config.redirectUri = window.location.origin + "/login";

  // The SPA's id. The SPA is registered with this id at the auth-server
  this.config.clientId = 'xxxxxxxxx';

   // Use setStorage to use sessionStorage or another implementation of the TS-type Storage
    // instead of localStorage
    this.oauthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);

    // set to true, to receive also an id_token via OpenId Connect (OIDC) in addition to the
    // OAuth2-based access_token
    this.oauthService.oidc = true; // ID_Token

  // set the scope for the permissions the client should request 
  // The first three are defined by OIDC. The 4th is a usecase-specific one
  this.config.scope = 'openid profile email roles xxxxx';

//  this.config.responseType = 'code';

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  private ConfigureImplicitFlowAuthentication() {


    this.oauthService.configure(this.config);

      this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
      const url = 'https://my-identity-domain.azurewebsites.net/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration';
      this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument(url).then((doc) => {
        this.oauthService.tryLogin({})
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            })
            .then(() => {
                if(!this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
          console.log("Implicit flow has been called initImplicitFlow "); 
                    this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
                }
            });
      });
  }

  private configure() { 
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
    const url = 'https://my-identity-domain.azurewebsites.net/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration';   
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument(url);
    this.oauthService.initLoginFlow();
  }
  public login() {



       console.log('configured open id' , this.config);
       this.oauthService.configure(this.config);
       this.ConfigureImplicitFlowAuthentication();
      // this.configure();


       //this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
//       this.ConfigureImplicitFlowAuthentication();

       /*

       this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument(url).then((doc) => {
         console.log('loaded doc 123-  : ' , doc);
         this.oauthService.tryLogin()
         .catch(err => {
           console.error(err);
         })
         .then(() => {
           if(!this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
             this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow()
           }
         });
         console.debug('discovery succeeded', doc);
       });

        */
       console.log('opein id failed');
       //this.oauthService.events.subscribe(e => e instanceof OAuthErrorEvent ? console.error(e) : console.warn(e));

       // Load information from Auth0 (could also be configured manually)
       //this.ConfigureImplicitFlowAuthentication();
  }

  public logoff() {
      this.oauthService.logOut();
  }

  public get name() {
      let claims = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
      if (!claims) return null;
      console.log("claim object");
      console.log(claims);
      return claims["given_name"];
  }


}
```

on calling the **login** function it redirects to a page which needs says **Hmm, you either used the incorrect login details or have not signed up yet** but its its suppose to be redirected to the login page as l have called
 **this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();**.

its redirecting to 
https://my-identity-domain.azurewebsites.net/identity/connect/authorize?response_type=id_token%20token&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&state=Psh7Ihio8Tv-JzrmG1ScmoZhB47SsjO-PqQoxyX0vhwbL&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Findex.html&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20roles%20xxxxxxx%20xxxxxxxx&nonce=Psh7Ihio8Tv-JzrmG1ScmoZhB47SsjO-PqQoxyX0vhwbL

**but the web forms is redirecting to**

https://my-identity-domain.azurewebsites.net/identity/login?signin=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

what makes me worry is that in the asp.net webform app its working but on angular version the new app being developed its not its been three days trying many examples online what can l do ??

i have also tried https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc and used credentials there it worked but when i replace with mine its not working